# curl post request in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl

I want to convert this post request written in curl (GoPay payment gateway) to my Rails application:

```
curl -v https://gw.sandbox.gopay.com/api/oauth2/token \
-X "POST" \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
-u "<Client ID>:<Client Secret>" \
-d "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=payment-create"
```

I am trying to do in my rails controller by using a gem **rest-client**. I've done something like this and was modifiying many times but couldn't make it works:

```
RestClient::Request.execute( method: :post, 
                             url: "https://gw.sandbox.gopay.com/api/oauth2/token",
                             "#{ENV['GOPAY_CLIENT_ID']}": "#{ENV['GOPAY_CLIENT_SECRET']}"
                             data: "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=payment-create" 
                             )
```

How I can convert the curl post request for the rest-client (or similar)?

EDIT: It is showing a status code 409: Conflict with no further information

EDIT1 - rgo's modified code works, thank you:

```
RestClient.post "https://#{ENV['GOPAY_CLIENT_ID']}:#{ENV['GOPAY_CLIENT_SECRET']}@gw.sandbox.gopay.com/api/oauth2/token", 
    { grant_type: 'client_credentials', scope: 'payment-create'}, 
    content_type: :json, accept: :json
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a RestClient user but after reading the documentation[1] I think I transformed your cURL request to RestClient:

```
RestClient.post "http://#{ENV['GOPAY_CLIENT_ID']}:#{ENV['GOPAY_CLIENT_SECRET']}@https://gw.sandbox.gopay.com/api/oauth2/token",
                { grant_type: 'client_credentials', scope: 'payment-create'},
                content_type: :json,
                accept: :json
```

As you can see I pass the credentials in the URL because is a basic authentication. Data(grant_type and scope) is passed as hash and then converted to JSON. Then we set rest client to send and receive JSON.

I hope it helps you

[1] https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client#usage-raw-url

Comment: Cool! After I took away the extension .to_json it works. Thank you!

Comment: Answer updated as you said: .to_json call has been removed

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention exactly what doesn't work or what error you're seeing. However, the `-u` option for curl is used to pass the username and password for [basic authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).

The equivalent for RestClient is to use the `user` and `password` options e.g.

```
RestClient::Request.execute(
  method: :post, 
  url: "https://gw.sandbox.gopay.com/api/oauth2/token",
  user: "#{ENV['GOPAY_CLIENT_ID']}",
  password: "#{ENV['GOPAY_CLIENT_SECRET']}"
  data: "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=payment-create",
  headers: { "Accept" => "application/json", "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencode" }
)
```

Comment: Sorry, I updated my post. My attempt as well as this one is showing a conflict 409: *** RestClient::Conflict Exception: 409 Conflict

Comment: Checking the GoPay docs https://doc.gopay.com/en/#access-token the Accept and Content-Type headers are required so try adding them. Am away from the laptop now but should be something like the updated answer.